# Possible to create a conda environment from anaconda in a server?

Tags: anaconda, conda, virtualenv, hpc

I am trying to install a specific piece of software to my university hpc3 server. On the tutorial for the installation it says that a conda environment in needed to install. However I am denied permission from installing conda. Anaconda is installed in the server, which is confusing me since I thought anaconda has conda within it.

Anaconda version is 33.16.8.9.
The server distro is Rocky 8.8 Green obsidian if it helps

I tried to create a normal python venv but some of the packages I need to install are not possible to download using "pip install". I also tried to install conda using pip, it worked but then whenever i used the "conda install" command the package would say that I have the wrong form of conda because I downloaded it using "pip install".

Comment: Can you include the commands you used to load conda, create and activate and env and then install your packages?

Comment: I think you trying to install anything at all just circumvents the underlying issue how you can use the pre-installed anaconda to create your own env. I would suggest you write your universities IT administration and ask them how you can create your own conda env in their system

Answer (score 0):

Install `conda` (not `anaconda`) in your home directory, which I assume you have permissions for. I am using `conda` because it is simpler, and in my field (bioinformatics) it is a very common tool to install one or more tools into a specific environment and manage the dependencies correctly. You do not have to have special privileges for `conda` other than r/w/x in your home directory.

Do not use `anaconda` or `pip` for installing `conda`, because `conda` should be an independently installed tool to easily update or uninstall/reinstall it.

The directions for `conda` installation are here:

[Installing on Linux — conda documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html)

After the install, `conda` executable will be available for you here: `~/miniconda3/bin/conda`.

Comment: You probalby meant "Install `miniconda` (not `anaconda`)`". You should give some details though why you think that OP should install miniconda and not anaconda and why they should install anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the tips, I have resolved my issue. Anaconda is a module that is available in my university server, from there I load the anaconda module using the "module load" command and then Conda is available to me. I'm new to linux so thank you for bearing with me.